# rospy: throttling logmessage rate?

Tags: ros, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In roscpp we can use the `ROS_*_THROTTLE(..)` macros, but rospy doesn't seem to have anything like that.

Any suggestions as to what would be the most elegant / pythonic way of achieving something equivalent in rospy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94016/rospy:-throttling-logmessage-rate?/) by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86574 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update (2016-06-03): a recent [PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/812) added support for throttled logging in Python. See [wiki/rospy/Overview/Logging - Logging Periodically](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging#Logging_Periodically).

---

Answering my own question:

It would seem this is rather difficult to implement in Python. The `ROS_*_THROTTLE(..)` macro can exploit some features of C/C++ (variable scoping, static variables): state information is inserted *for every individual invocation of the macro* (see [ros/console.h#L422-433](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/4f7572cea43d3f85ca7f8bff7a75174f2d9d758a/tools/rosconsole/include/ros/console.h#L422-433)). This makes it possible to easily support multiple calls with different `period` arguments, without resorting to for instance `__FILE__ __LINE__` trickery (which wouldn't work anyway).

Python does not support this, and would require a different approach. After some experimentation, adding runtime, per-invocation state information seems hard to implement, at least in a way supported by the many runtimes in existence and/or Python 3+. One approach could be to use a `(object_id, function_name, line_nr)` tuple to uniquely identify an invocation. Unfortunately it seems impossible to retrieve this information without the use of functionality not supported everywhere (`inspect` and / or `sys._getframe()`). This would also shift the responsibility of keeping track of previous invocations to the `log*throttle(..)` implementations.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5